# nodejs Sharp: transparent into white

Tags: node.js, jpeg, transparency, sharp

I am using Nodejs Sharp to transcode/resize png images into jpg. Is there way to replace transparent with white (or other light color) rather than black? I found solution for an older library but Sharp seems to be fastest and greatest.

.background does not work

```
.then( data => Sharp(data.Body)
  .resize(SIZES[resize_type].width, SIZES[resize_type].height)
  .max()
  .withoutEnlargement()
  .background("white")
  .toFormat('jpeg')
  .toBuffer()
)
```

Comment: lol I want the opposite

Answer (score 6, accepted):

by the document, we should do the way as Msalam suggest but unluckily that is not enough. I figured out We should add .flatten(true) before ".resize(...)" to make it work correctly.

Answer (score 31):

On version `^0.23` you can use `flatten(options)` as api document here: https://sharp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-operation/#flatten

```js
sharp('input.png').flatten({ background: { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 } })
```

Comment: Note: You also can use `.flatten({ background: '#ffffff' })` to make it's white.

Answer (score 11):

from the [sharp documentation](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-operation#flatten)  as it states that you can use the background for color manipulations and it states that

> The default background is  {r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, alpha: 1}, black without transparency.

so inorder to get white simply use

```
.background({r: 255, g: 255, b: 255, alpha: 1})
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add :

```
.flatten({ background: '#fff' })
```